# Apps flickering on homepage

Tags: iphone, ios

On my home screen, sometimes apps blink or flicker in a random order. Does anyone know what this means, or is it just some sort of glitch?

Comment: When the app icon is flickering, does the app name changes to say Cleaning...?

Answer (score 2):

This is an optimization task being performed by the iOS. The app icons flicker, i.e. the icon becomes grayed and the name of the app is replaced with the word Cleaning.... iOS is removing temporary files and cached app data.

Comment: No, that’s different. I have seen exactly what you described before, but it’s not what I meant in the question I asked. Basically, the app icon just becomes greyed out, and then goes back to normal - as if someone has tapped on it. (Sorry I didn’t reply to your comment - I’ve only just seen it.)

Comment: @DM01131 exactly same thing happened on my iPhone.  My device had very little free space left and I was installing an app from App Store and this happened. This answer really makes sense in my context